# Flutter PathNotFoundException: Creation failed, path

Tags: android, database, flutter, dart, sqflite

All error text on vs code:

```
ccccccccccccccccc PathNotFoundException: Cannot copy file to '/data/user/0/com.example.habit_tracker/app_flutter/habit_tracker.db', path = '/data/user/0/com.example.habit_tracker/cache/databases/habit_tracker.db' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

I have a sqflite database for my application. And I want to backup, restore and delete database. Delete is working for the database But backup and restore is not working. The resore method is not working because I can't backup any file on my file explorer. So the method cannot find the backup file. The main problem is backup method. How can I fix this problem.

DatabaseHelper class for my functions.

```
class DatabaseHelper {
  getDbPath() async {
    String databasePath = await getDatabasesPath();
    print("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa $databasePath");
    Directory? externalStoragePath = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    print("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb$externalStoragePath");
  }

  

     backupDb() async {
Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
String tempPath = tempDir.path;

Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;

print(tempPath);   //  /data/user/0/com.example.habit_tracker/cache
print(appDocPath); //  /data/user/0/com.example.habit_tracker/app_flutter

var status = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.status;
if (!status.isGranted) {
  await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
}
var status1 = await Permission.storage.status;
if (!status1.isGranted) {
  await Permission.storage.request();
}

try {
  var destinationFile = File(
      "$appDocPath/habit_tracker.db");
  var folderPathForDbFile = destinationFile.parent;
  File ourDbFile = File(
      '$tempPath/databases/habit_tracker.db');
  await folderPathForDbFile.create(recursive: true);
  await ourDbFile.copy(
      "$appDocPath/habit_tracker.db");
} catch (e) {
  print("ccccccccccccccccc ${e.toString()}");
}
  }

  restoreDb() async {
    var status = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.status;
    if (!status.isGranted) {
      await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
    }

    var status1 = await Permission.storage.status;
    if (!status1.isGranted) {
      await Permission.storage.request();
    }

    try {
      File savedDbFile = File(
          "/storage/emulated/0/habit_tracker_files/databases/habit_tracker.db");
      await savedDbFile.copy(
          "/data/user/0/com.example.habit_tracker/databases/habit_tracker.db");
    } catch (e) {
      print("dddddddddddd  ${e.toString()}");
    }
  }

  deleteDb() async {
    try {
      var database = null;
      deleteDatabase(
          '/data/user/0/com.example.habit_tracker/databases/habit_tracker.db');
    } catch (e) {
      print("eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee${e.toString()}");
    }
  }
}
```

This is simple statlesswidget to use these 3 methods. I have 3 elevated button.

```
class help extends StatelessWidget {
  const help({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                DatabaseHelper().backupDb();
              },
              child: const Text("bakup")),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                DatabaseHelper().restoreDb();
              },
              child: const Text("restore")),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                DatabaseHelper().deleteDb();
              },
              child: const Text("delete"))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.habit_tracker">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
   <application
        android:label="Life Tracker"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And lastly I have these packages inside my pubspec.yaml

```
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1             #google fontlarını denemek için. belli font seçilince kaldıracağım. normal yolla ekleyeceğim.
  flutter_riverpod: ^1.0.4         #state managment için
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15      #local database için
  intl: ^0.17.0                    #date format için kullanıyorum
  flutter_slidable: ^2.0.0         #slidable listview özellikleri için
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0             #local database için
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.11.0  #Uygulamanın logosunu değiştirmek için
  shimmer: ^2.0.0                  #shimmer effect eklemek için
  
  sqflite: ^2.2.3                  #local database için
  permission_handler: ^10.2.0      #permission için
  path_provider: ^2.0.13
```

I used this video for code
https://youtu.be/KhtLPi9MsQ4

Comment: You should first check if the destination folder is created and exists. On Android 11+ devices it will not.

Comment: Hmm. I understand but İf I check the file is exist. I will get exist. Because I think the problem about create the file. Am I wrong. Help me please. I am new in flutter

Answer (score 3):

> ```dart
>     File ourDbFile = File(
>          '/data/user/0/com.example.habit_tracker/databases/habit_tracker.db');
>      Directory folderPathForDbFile = Directory(
>          "/storage/emulated/0/habit_tracker_files/databases/habit_tracker.db");
>      await folderPathForDbFile.create();
>      await ourDbFile.copy(
>          "/storage/emulated/0/habit_tracker_files/databases/habit_tracker.db");
> ```

There are a few things wrong:

1. `Directory("/storage/emulated/0/habit_tracker_files/databases/habit_tracker.db")` creates a `Directory` object corresponding to that exact path, not to the parent directory of that path.  That is, when you do `folderPathForDbFile.create()`, assuming that it succeeds, it would create a directory/folder named `habit_tracker.db`.  Subsequently attempting to create a `habit_tracker.db` *file* would fail because something with that name (a directory) would already exist.  You instead want:

   ```dart
   var destinationFile = File("/storage/emulated/0/habit_tracker_files/databases/habit_tracker.db");
   var folderPathForDbFile = destinationFile.parent;
   ```
2. [`Directory.create()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/Directory/create.html) without specifying `recursive: true` will not create any missing parent directories.  If some of the directories in that path might not exist, you should use:

   ```dart
   await folderPathForDbFile.create(recursive: true);
   ```
3. You shouldn't be hard-coding the `/data/user/0/com.example.habit_tracker/` and `/storage/emulated/0/` paths.  Use [`package:path_provider`](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I edit my code with your reports. But I can't fix the error. Because I don't understand well the problem. Actually  my english is not good enough. Please look again my codes. This is important for me